# Using node js to replace multiple strings in a html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, writefile

I'm trying to create a tool that will allow me to quickly update several text strings in an html file. I'm doing this by searching for the contents of tags with specific ids and then replacing their text content. I've got much of it working but I'm not sure how to enable this to write multiple replacements into the file. As it is, it's simply running only the last of my replacements.

Here's what I have:

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('sample.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  var title1 = "boogers"
  var text1 = "ronald mcdonald";

  var result = data.replace(/<div id="text1">(.*)<\/div>/g, '<div id="text1">' + text1 + '</div>'); 
  var result = data.replace(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/g, '<title>' + title1 + '</title>'); 
    fs.writeFile('sample.html', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  }); 
});
```

In the code above, it will replace the title's content but not the div tag's. I imagine this is a pretty basic fix but I'm new to node js and javascript. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the `sample.html` and the expected output from it?

Comment: The problem here because you are overriding the result 
Second line should be **result = result.replace**

Answer (score 3):

You are "creating" variable **result** twice, and attributing the replacement over **data** twice. So, in the second attribution you loose the replacement done before. Try this:

```
fs.readFile('sample.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  var title1 = "boogers"
  var text1 = "ronald mcdonald";

  var result = data.replace(/<div id="text1">(.*)<\/div>/g, '<div id="text1">' + text1 + '</div>'); 
  result = result.replace(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/g, '<title>' + title1 + '</title>'); 
    fs.writeFile('sample.html', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Awesome! So is this line:
result = result.replace(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/g, '<title>' + title1 + '</title>');
basically saying "set result to be the previously set contents (e.g. the replacement of the div tag) plus this new content (e.g. the replacement of the div tag)?

Comment: @WForbis Yes. Exactly.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use "//g" global method

```
var str = "aaabbcccasbbbb"; //main string
var repStr = "ss";  //replace string
var result = str.replace(/[ab]/g, repStr);  //result
console.log(result);
```

Result will be: sssssssssscccsssssssssss

Comment: This is not the point, we want to do it from a file, not from a string...